# Best way to split IQueryable<List<object>> into different sections and filter each section

Tags: c#, .net, list, iqueryable

I've got an `IQueryable<List<object>>` the structure of the object is only an x-value and a y-value.
I also have another list which only contains double values.
My goal is to split the IQueryable based on the double values in my list and afterwards do a distinct on each of the splitted sections.

E.g.:

The Queryable:

```
var preparedQuery = new List<IReadOnlyList<object>>
{
    new List<object> { 100, 10 },
    new List<object> { 111, 20 },
    new List<object> { 112, 30 },
    new List<object> { 117, 60 },
    new List<object> { 150, 80 },
    new List<object> { 170, 90 },
    new List<object> { 257.527, 200 },
    new List<object> { 247.527, 100 }
}.AsQueryable();
```

The List:

```
var list = new List<double>
{
    50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300
}
```

The sections should now be like this (each section contains the objects where the x-value from the Queryable is >= the double value from the section and x-value < double value of the next section):

section for double value 50 (all values between 50-99): empty

section for double value 100 (all values between 100-149):

```
new List<object> { 100, 10 },
new List<object> { 111, 20 },
new List<object> { 112, 30 },
new List<object> { 117, 60 }
```

section for double value 150 (all values between 150-199):

```
new List<object> { 150, 80 },
new List<object> { 170, 90 },
```

section for double value 200:

```
new List<object> { 247.527, 100 }
```

section for double value 250:

```
new List<object> { 257.527, 200 }
```

section for double value 300: empty

After splitting these values, there should be executed a distinct() on each section and after that I want them to be put together to a Queryable again.
Now I want to find a Linq statement for example, which can solve this problem.

Comment: Have you tried anything? where did you get issue the code you tried?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Linq's [GroupBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby) extension for your IQueryable source in combination with [List.BinarySearch(T, IComparer)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.binarysearch?view=netframework-4.8) for finding the grouping key from your sorted list.

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var preparedQuery = new List<IReadOnlyList<object>>
    {
        new List<object> { 100, 10 },
        new List<object> { 111, 20 },
        new List<object> { 111, 20 },
        new List<object> { 112, 30 },
        new List<object> { 117, 60 },
        new List<object> { 150, 80 },
        new List<object> { 170, 90 },
        new List<object> { 257.527, 200 },
        new List<object> { 247.527, 100 }
    }.AsQueryable();

    var list = new List<double>
    {
        50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300
    };

    var preparedQuery1 = new List<IReadOnlyList<object>>();

    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        var s1 = preparedQuery
                    .Where(x => Convert.ToDouble(x[0]) >= list[i] 
                                && Convert.ToDouble(x[0]) < list[i+1] - 1)
                                .GroupBy(x1 => x1[0])
                    .ToList();

        var s2 = s1.Distinct().ToList(); // not sure this :)

        preparedQuery1.Add(s2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't this lead to index out of range exception at "list[i+1]"

Comment: I fixed that in above, is this what you want? You better put expected output